# Cannot query "zs": Must be "Product" instance

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, model

I want the seller to be able to choose one of the offers for sale and then close the sale by clicking on the close button.
This code doesn't do anything if I put a separate for loop in the html file, but if it's the way I sent it, it displays the button to close the sale, but after clicking the button, it gives this error.

*zs is the username.Also, I want each user to be able to make an offer only once.

and, I feel that this graphic is not very user-friendly. What is your suggestion for a better design and to reduce the number of buttons to close the auction?
[image: page view]

```
Error:

Exception Type: ValueError at /seller_page/


Exception Value: Cannot query "zs": Must be "Product" instance.
```

views.py:

```
def seller_page(request):
    seller_offers = PriceOffer.objects.filter(product=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        offer_id = request.POST.get('offer_id')
        offer = get_object_or_404(PriceOffer, pk=offer_id)
        offer.is_closed = True
        offer.save()
    return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', {'seller_offers': seller_offers})


def close_offer(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        offer_id = request.POST.get('offer_id') 
        offer = get_object_or_404(PriceOffer, pk=offer_id)
        offer.is_closed = True 
        offer.save() 
    return redirect('seller_page')
```

product_detail.html :

```
<ul>
     {% for offer in offers %}
          <li><a> {{ offer.author }}:{{ offer.offer_price }}</a></li>
            
          <form method="post" action="{% url 'close_offer' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden" name="offer_id" value="{{ offer.id }}">
              <button type="submit">Close Offer</button>
          </form>
            
     {% endfor %}

</ul>
    <form method="POST" action="{%url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="number" name="offer_price" placeholder="Offer Price">
        <button type="submit" name="offer">Submit Offer</button>
    </form>
```

models.py:

```
class PriceOffer(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    offer_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Price offer by {self.seller} on {self.product}: {self.offer_price}`
```

urls.py:

```
path('seller_page/', views.seller_page, name='seller_page'), 
path('close_offer/', views.close_offer, name='close_offer'),
```